# Как корректно декодировать тело письма, закодированного Base64?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, gmail

Есть объект письма, полученный AJAX GETом из ящика GMail https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages

Само тело письма закодировано base64, не получается корректно декодировать, всегда присутствует мусор.

Испробовал все найденные функции JavaScript и jQuery, побывал на стороне сервера base64_decode, тоже не помогло.
Лучший вариант, который дает читаемый текст, — это jquery.base64.js, но все равно присутствует мусор.

#### Пример результата декодирования

> Мы Ðтправили Вам этÐ Ðисьмо, Яотому что серьезнÐ ÐтнÐсимся к вÐЯрÐсам
>   безоÐасности и хотим, чтÐбы Вы были в курсе действий в Вашем аккаунте.
>   Нам не удалÐсь оÐределить, выÐолнÑлся ли вход в аккаунт через этот браузер
>   или устройство ранее. Возможно, Вы вÐервые вÐшли в систему на новом
>   комЯьютере, телефоне или в новÐм браузере. КрÐме тÐго, Вы мÐгли
>   просматривать пÐчту, находÑсь в режиме инкогнито, или просто удалить файлы
>   cookie. Если ничего ЯодобногÐ Вы не делали, высÐка вероятнÐсть, что Ваш
>   аккаунт был взломан.
>   КÐманда Google Аккаунтов

Подскажите варианты, как сделать правильно.

Comment: У гугла в доках к API ничего по этому поводу не написано?

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужна библиотека для **urlsafe** base64-декодирования.

Например

https://github.com/dankogai/js-base64

UPD:
Проще это сделать на стороне сервера.
Пример для PHP:

```
/**
 * Decodes from base64url
 *
 * @param string $data
 * @return string
 */
public function base64UrlDecode($data)
{
    if ($remainder = strlen($data) % 4) {
        $data .= str_repeat('=', 4 - $remainder);
    }

    return base64_decode(strtr($data, '-_', '+/'));
}
```

Comment: В ответе я описал возможный корень проблемы: "Как именно нужно обработать ответ от GMail" выбор библиотеки менее важен.

Comment: Ок :) . . . . .

Comment: Можно использовать только Gmail REST API, готовые API для работы с почтой Gmail использовать нельзя.
Поэтому вся обработка полученных данных вручную.
Воспользовался декодированием на стороне сервера предложенным выше.

Answer (score 0):

У меня этот **JavaScript** код прекрасно работает, возвращает письмо со всей разметкой и т.д.

```
function getBody(message) {
var encodedBody = '';
if (typeof message.parts === 'undefined') {
    encodedBody = message.body.data;
} else {
    encodedBody = getHTMLPart(message.parts);
}
encodedBody = encodedBody.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g,'/').replace(/\s/g, '');
return decodeURIComponent(escape(window.atob(encodedBody)));
}

function getHTMLPart(arr) {
for (var x = 0; x <= arr.length; x++) {
    if (typeof arr[x].parts === 'undefined') {
        if (arr[x].mimeType === 'text/html') {
            return arr[x].body.data;
        }
    }
    else {
        return getHTMLPart(arr[x].parts);
    }
}
return '';
}
```